Cannot insert keys and values in a map
I'd been trying to insert some key and values in the following way, but I'm getting an error:

error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'Edge'

I'm using C++17.
This is my program:
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>

struct Edge
{
    int v1{};
    int v2{};

    Edge (int v1, int v2)
    :v1{v1}, v2{v2}
    {
    }

};

int main()
{
    std::map<std::string, Edge> mymap;

    mymap["edge1"] = Edge(0,0);
    mymap["edge2"] = Edge(1,1);

    return 0;
}

I'm pretty sure my constructor is correct, but any help is highly appreciated.

When you refer to mymap["edge1"], the system has to construct a placeholder at that location, but you do not have a default constructor.  Perhaps you want to use emplace.

Yeah it's fixed after I added Edge() = default; very strange because in the tutorial that I'm following, the tutor is not even declaring any constructors. Maybe he's using a modern c++20 version, I'm not sure.

The default constructor is created for you by the compiler if and only if you have defined no other constructors. As soon ad you declared Edge (int v1, int v2), the compiler will use only the constructor you specified (and a synthesized copy constructor, but that will get you into trouble elsewhere)

@tadm123 Not declaring any constructors here would be equivalent to only defining the default constructor. So it would work. As you've added a user-defined constructor, the default constructor is now not implicitly generated by the compiler. Hence the error.

@ChrisMM I like this one. it's so old that the top-voted answer cites the original STL documentation.

Side note: A lot of the time you don't want the default constructor because you need the parameters for an instance to make any sense. It's better to force complete initialization of the object to having to add tests all through the code to make sure the instance is viable before it's used. Edge is simple enough that you can (and did) default initialize all of the members to sensible values, but even then ideologically you may not want a default constructor as it sends the wrong message to users who may start cranking out [0,0] default-constructed instances and shoot themselves in the foot.


As commented, the emplace() call is missing from your code:

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>

struct Edge
{
    int v1{};
    int v2{};
    Edge() = default;
    Edge(int v1, int v2) : v1{v1}, v2{v2} {}
};

int main()
{
    std::map<std::string, Edge> mymap;

    mymap.emplace("edge1", Edge(0, 0));
    mymap.emplace("edge2", Edge(1, 1));
    mymap.emplace("edge2", Edge(2, 2));
    mymap.emplace("edge3", Edge(3, 3));

    for (const auto &pair : mymap)
    {
        std::cout << pair.first << " " << pair.second.v1 << " " << pair.second.v2 << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}


The details of emplace() can be found in this link.

In this link insert vs emplace vs operator[] in c++ has been further explained.


Note:
operator[] first checks the container to see if the element already exists. If exists, a reference to the existing element is returned. If not, a new element is default constructed in the container and a reference to it is returned. Since Edge has no default constructor, this cannot happen and the program fails to compile. If Edge had a default constructor, the returned element would then be assigned the value of the temporary Edge the asker wanted to insert.
On the other hand, Emplace() constructs the new Edge "in place" and avoids the need to construct a temporary and copy or move it, which is a bit more efficient.
Useful link:
Overview of std::map’s Insertion / Emplacement Methods in C++17
